# APi management to Logic App: 404 not found

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have developed a solution using Azure Logic Apps and ApI management in Azure. API in Azure APi management call Azure logic App workflow [http trigger] as backend service.

The solution works fine with Azure logic App on one resource, Test. When I create the same logic App in another resource, Pre-production, I am receiving 404 Not found error.

I have two resource for API management [Test and pre-prod] and corresponding two  logic app resource groups, [test and pre-prod].  The connection from both API management API is successful to Logic App in Test resource group.

However, when I try to connect to logic app workflow on Pre-prod, I am encountering 404 Not Found Error. I can select the workflow as back-end service through API management interface.

I have tested Logic App Workflow using postman and it works fine. It is only the API in API management which cannot connect.

I try to investigate using Trace but it does not provide any clue.

Any suggestions and help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was a return status coming back from logic apps, which was resource specific. otherwise, The call from API manager was going fine.